# Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-java-config

I am getting the following Exception with a Spring4/Hibernate4 project I converted from xml- to Java-Config.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

The project starts up property and errorfree in Eclipse, but on the first request the Exception appears. In my `ConfigRoot`-class I have `@Bean` configured for `DataSource`, `SessionFactory`, `HibernateTransactionManager`, `ImprovedNamingStrategy`.

All my `@Service` services are annotated with `@Transactional`.

Any idea where this could come from ?

**Edit 1**

As requested, here the stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    employees.service.PersonService.getAllInHierarchcalOrder(PersonService.java:58)
    employees.controller.PersonController.getPersons(PersonController.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

**Edit 2**

Strangely, I borrowed the whole Java-Config code from another project which works flawlessly, certainly I missed a detail. That's why I am not considering [Some transaction propagations not working with Spring/Hibernate 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569365/some-transaction-propagations-not-working-with-spring-hibernate-4).

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569365/some-transaction-propagations-not-working-with-spring-hibernate-4).

Comment: If at least you showed the stacktrace ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found it ... `@EnableTransactionManagement` was missing on my root configuration class.

Thanks everybody for the guidance.

Comment: I have not used @EnableTransactionManagement till now. All my service layers and dao layers were working fine till now. Suddenly I came across this problem. Moreover, the same dao has one save method, and it works fine. Only when I try to create criteria, it is giving problem. The other dao is still working fine. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I presume it is a problem of transactional proxy not being used (just a guess from the stacktrace). By default, spring uses a Jdk proxy for it, but that needs the service to be imported *as an interface* in the controller.

If it is the case, create an interface `IPersonService` containing relevant method from `PersonService` and import it in `PersonController` as `@Autowired IPersonService personService;` or even better, rename `PersonService` to `PersonServiceImpl` and make `PersonService` an interface.

And ... consistently do that for all your transactional services ...

Answer (score 0):

Such scenario:

Use this **Thumb Rule** :

1) For Every @Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")

Create corresponding Services, and Corresponding DAO.