# used @Transactional but still getting : Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm having this error for days, ***please*** look into my codes:

error codes:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:136)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:496)
    com.test.dao.DoctorDAOImpl.getDoctor(DoctorDAOImpl.java:34)
    com.test.service.MainServiceImpl.getDoctor(MainServiceImpl.java:39)
    com.test.controller.MainController.showMain(MainController.java:23)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-mysql.properties"})
public class Config {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        System.out.println("\ntesting "+env.getProperty("jdbc.url")+"\n\n");
        return  viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {

        // create connection pool
        ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        // set the jdbc driver
        try {
            myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");       
        }
        catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }

        // for sanity's sake, let's log url and user ... just to make sure we are reading the data
        logger.info("jdbc.url=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        logger.info("jdbc.user=" + env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));

        // set database connection props
        myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));

        // set connection pool props
        myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize"));
        myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));     
        myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime"));

        return myDataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        // set hibernate properties
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        return props;               
    }


    // need a helper method 
    // read environment property and convert to int

    private int getIntProperty(String propName) {

        String propVal = env.getProperty(propName);

        // now convert to int
        int intPropVal = Integer.parseInt(propVal);

        return intPropVal;
    }   

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){

        // create session factorys
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        // set the properties
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        // setup transaction manager based on session factory
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }
}
```

MainServiceImpl.java

```
package com.test.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.test.dao.DoctorDAO;
import com.test.dao.PatientDAO;
import com.test.entity.Doctor;
import com.test.entity.Patient;

@Service
public class MainServiceImpl implements MainService {

    @Autowired
    private PatientDAO patientDao;

    @Autowired
    private DoctorDAO doctorDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        System.out.println("inside service: getPatients method");
        return patientDao.getPatients();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Patient getPatient(int theId) {
        return patientDao.getPatient(theId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Doctor getDoctor(int theId) {
        return doctorDao.getDoctor(theId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addPatient(Patient thePatient) {
        patientDao.savePatient(thePatient);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addDoctor(Doctor theDoctor) {
        doctorDao.saveDoctor(theDoctor);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deletePatient(int theId) {
        patientDao.deletePatient(theId);
    }

}
```

MainController.java

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.test.entity.Doctor;
import com.test.service.MainService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("main")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private MainService service;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @Transactional
    public String showMain(Model theModel) {
        System.out.println("inside show Main method");
        Doctor theDoctor = service.getDoctor(1);
//      List<Patient> thePatients = service.getPatients();
//      System.out.println(thePatients);
        theModel.addAttribute("doctor", theDoctor);
        return "main";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.practice</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>test</name>
  <properties>
        <springframework.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>5.0.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>

        <hibernate.version>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Spring orm and tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security JSP tag support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add MySQL and C3P0 support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet, JSP and JSTL support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- to compensate for java 9+ not including jaxb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>test</finalName>
      <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- Add maven coordinates: maven-war-plugin -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

DoctorDAOImpl.java

```
package com.test.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.test.entity.Doctor;
import com.test.entity.Patient;

@Repository
public class DoctorDAOImpl implements DoctorDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Patient> getPatients(int theId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query<Patient> theQuery = session.createQuery("from Patient p where p.doctor.id=:doctorId");
        theQuery.setParameter("doctorId", theId);
        List<Patient> result = theQuery.getResultList();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Doctor getDoctor(int theId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.get(Doctor.class, theId);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveDoctor(Doctor theDoctor) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(theDoctor);
    }

}
```

PatientDAOImpl.java

```
package com.test.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.test.entity.Patient;

@Repository
public class PatientDAOImpl implements PatientDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Patient> getPatients() {
        System.out.println("inside repository: getPatients method");
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Patient> theQuery = session.createQuery("from Patient",Patient.class);
        return theQuery.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void savePatient(Patient thePatient) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(thePatient);
    }

    @Override
    public Patient getPatient(int theId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return session.get(Patient.class,theId);
    }

    @Override
    public void deletePatient(int theId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query theQuery = session.createQuery("delete from Patient where id=:patientId");
        theQuery.setParameter("patientId", theId);
        theQuery.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

> I'm sorry that I dumped all my code here, but this is the best I could do.

Comment: `@Transactional` without ` @EnableTransactionManagement` does nothing. Add that annotation. Also don't start a transaction using `beginTransaction` on the session .Spring already manages all of that for you.

Comment: @M. Deinum, please accept my sincere thanks for helping me. My project is working now, all because of your help. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using the search before posting a question, as this has been asked multiple times on Stack Overflow. Besides @m-deinum's comment (props go to him!) you would have found the answer e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203682/3890673) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180076/3890673) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50739929/3890673): Please add `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation.